# Error when I call transfer function in ERC20 contract from other contract, But, can use mint/burn

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I write 2 contracts

- ERC20
- ERC721 with additional function for buy it.

> when call "marketBuy" function it can transfer NFT to buyer and can
> call burn from ERC20 contract. But when I change "burn" function to
> "transfer / transferFrom" then appear error like this
>
> transact to NFT2.marketBuy pending ...  transact to NFT2.marketBuy
> errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

This is the code

```
    ...

    function marketBuy(uint _tokenId) public returns (bool) {
        address _buyer = msg.sender;
        uint _price = marketItem[_tokenId].price;

        IERC20(ERC20Token).approve(marketItem[_tokenId].seller, _price);
        IERC20(ERC20Token).transferFrom(_buyer, marketItem[_tokenId].seller, _price);
        transferFrom(marketItem[_tokenId].seller, _buyer, _tokenId);
        
        marketItem[_tokenId].seller = _buyer;
        marketItem[_tokenId].isSold = true;

        return true;
    }
    
    ....
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this line

```
IERC20(ERC20Token).approve(marketItem[_tokenId].seller, _price);
```

the caller is the contract itself, it isn't the buyer.

So the buyer needs to call the `transfer` function manually on the ERC-20 contract